# r identify and return string prior to last delimiter

Tags: r, regex, string, delimiter

I have found similar questions on stackoverflow, but not exactly what I'm looking for. I have a vector like:

```
x <- c('w/x/y/z', 'x/y/z', 'y/z')
```

I want to return a vector that gives me the string (in my real data, a longer string than 1 letter) that is before the last / and prior to any other /. So, the output for this would be:

```
y <- c('y', 'y', 'y')
```

I have tried using strsplit and tail to split by / and return the last 2 items, but don't know how to only get the second to last item.

```
y <- sapply(lapply(spl, tail,2), paste, collapse = '/')
y
[1] "y/z" "y/z" "y/z"
```

Comment: Yes, I want to select the string between the last / symbol and the / prior to it. However, there is not always a / prior (like the third string, 'y/z').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ifelse(grepl("/", x), sapply(strsplit(x, "/"), function(S) tail(S, 2)[1]), NA)
#[1] "y" "y" "y"
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it! My issue was actually that the x column was a factor, not a character.